# Collecting data without IO in Scalpel

Tags: haskell

I'm using Haskell's [Scalpel library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel-0.5.1/docs/Text-HTML-Scalpel.html) as an intro to web scraping in Haskell.  I can call a function `scrapeURL` which allows me to scrape a page and output it to IO, but I can't find a function that just allows me to simply return the output of the call.

```
import Text.HTML.Scalpel

data WikiImg
    =  Src String
    deriving (Show, Eq)

...

rembrantImagesIO :: IO (Maybe [WikiImg])
rembrantImagesIO = scrapeURL "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt" wikimgs

rembrantImages :: Maybe [WikiImg]
rembrantImages = scrapeStringLike "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt" wikimgs

wikimgs :: Scraper String [WikiImg]
wikimgs = chroots ("div" @: [hasClass "thumbinner"]) wikimg
  where
    wikimg :: Scraper String WikiImg
    wikimg =  do
     src   <- attr "src" $ "img"
     return $ Src src
```

`rembrantImagesIO` will output a list of img src's

```
Just [Src "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/Rembrandt_-_Rembrandt_and_Saski...
```

...but `rembrantImages` seems to fail.

`Just []`

How can I simply return a `Maybe [WikiImg]` that actually returns something?

(Side note: I see little on StackOverflow about Scalpel...if you are experienced with web scraping in Haskell, please let me know if there is a better place to start.)

Comment: I don't think scrapeStringLike works the way you think it does. You're passing it a URL, and it's trying to scrape the literal URL.  It's expecting a string that represents HTML.  You could verify this by feeding that function some HTML that contains something you think you could scrape...

Comment: This seems like consistent behavior. Scraping a webpage from the internet involves touching the impure outside world, so it has to be tainted with the IO monad. It can scrape HTML happily enough if you provide it, but if you only go and tell it where the HTML lives, then it has to be IO.